# XSLT3 - xml-to-json() function generate un-escaped json

Tags: json, xslt-3.0

Using Saxon XSLT 3.0 I am trying to convert XML to JSON. The first step is to convert the input XML into the required Maps & Array format the xml-to-json() required format.

When I then call the function with

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$target_json}" method="json">
    <xsl:copy-of select="xml-to-json($intermediate_XML, map{., 'indent':false() })"></xsl:copy-of>
</xsl:result-document>
```

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <string key="headline">Matilda sold such dreadful ties</string>
   <string key="body">
&lt;p&gt;Matilda sold such dreadful ties.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;It made Juan retch and...&lt;/p&gt;
</string>
</map>
```

JSON Result

`"\n  { \"headline\" : \"Matilda sold such dreadful ties\",\n    \"body\" : \"\\n<p>Matilda sold such dreadful ties.<\\\/p>\\n<p>It made Juan retch and...<\\\/p>\\n\" }"`

What I expected and need is

`{ "headline" : "Matilda sold such dreadful ties", "body" : "\n<p>Matilda sold such dreadful ties.<\/p>\n<p>It made Juan retch and...<\/p>\n" }`

Without the Starting and ending quote " and all the escaped characters.

Any assistance would be most welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want both output method as `json` and also use `xml-to-json`, use output method `text` for the result of that function.

[Example using Saxon HE 11](https://martin-honnen.github.io/cheerpj-saxon-worker/index-workbench.html?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22text%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22xml-to-json%28.%2C%20map%20%7B%20%27indent%27%20%3A%20true%28%29%20%7D%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22US-ASCII%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cmap%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Cstring%20key%3D%22headline%22%3EMatilda%20sold%20such%20dreadful%20ties%3C%2Fstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Cstring%20key%3D%22body%22%3E%0D%0A%26lt%3Bp%26gt%3BMatilda%20sold%20such%20dreadful%20ties.%26lt%3B%2Fp%26gt%3B%0D%0A%26lt%3Bp%26gt%3BIt%20made%20Juan%20retch%20and...%26lt%3B%2Fp%26gt%3B%0D%0A%3C%2Fstring%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fmap%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML).

[Another example using Saxon HE 11 in an Azure backend, this time with xsl:result-document](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xml-workbench/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22html%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%20html-version%3D%225%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aresult-document%20href%3D%22example1.json%22%20method%3D%22text%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22xml-to-json%28.%2C%20map%20%7B%20%27indent%27%20%3A%20true%28%29%20%7D%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aresult-document%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22US-ASCII%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cmap%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2005%2Fxpath-functions%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Cstring%20key%3D%22headline%22%3EMatilda%20sold%20such%20dreadful%20ties%3C%2Fstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Cstring%20key%3D%22body%22%3E%0D%0A%26lt%3Bp%26gt%3BMatilda%20sold%20such%20dreadful%20ties.%26lt%3B%2Fp%26gt%3B%0D%0A%26lt%3Bp%26gt%3BIt%20made%20Juan%20retch%20and...%26lt%3B%2Fp%26gt%3B%0D%0A%3C%2Fstring%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fmap%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML).

The output method `json` is useful if you represent your data as XDM 3.1 maps/arrays e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:sequence
      select='map { "headline" : "Matilda sold such dreadful ties", "body" : "&#10;&lt;p>Matilda sold such dreadful ties.&lt;/p>&#10;&lt;p>It made Juan retch and...&lt;/p>&#10;" }'/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online example](https://martin-honnen.github.io/cheerpj-saxon-worker/index-workbench.html?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22json%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20select%3D%27map%20%7B%20%22headline%22%20%3A%20%22Matilda%20sold%20such%20dreadful%20ties%22%2C%20%22body%22%20%3A%20%22%26%2310%3B%26lt%3Bp%3EMatilda%20sold%20such%20dreadful%20ties.%26lt%3B%2Fp%3E%26%2310%3B%26lt%3Bp%3EIt%20made%20Juan%20retch%20and...%26lt%3B%2Fp%3E%26%2310%3B%22%20%7D%27%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=&code-type=XSLT&input-type=None).

Comment: Thankyou Martin, your special website does provide the result I expected.

I notice that you are not using xsl:result-document in your code and when I apply you suggestion to use method="text" the output remains the same for me.  

Could  xsl:result-document be affecting this?

I could append an extra step to the processing pipeline using you solution if required.

Comment: @Binsky, I have added another sample link where `xsl:result-document` is supported, the created `example1.json` (you need to select that after using the XSLT button) has the same contents as the principal result from the previous example. So no, using `xsl:result-document` should make no difference, the point is, `xml-to-json` gives you a string with the JSON, if you use `method="text"`, you get that JSON string, if you use `method="json"`, you get the JSON string escaped as a JSON string.